# XML Disappears in Script Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to add a new child node to an XML request I'm proxying through to WSO2 DSS using an API.

The request I receive is in the following format:

```
<contacts>
  <firstName>Bob</firstName>
  <lastName>Brown</lastName>
</contacts>
```

I need to add an "id" node to this request that I can retrieve from a URI variable.

```
<contacts>
  <id>1</id>
  <firstName>Bob</firstName>
  <lastName>Brown</firstName>
</contacts>
```

I've tried using the "enrich" mediator, but this seems to just wrap the ID node around the first name and last name nodes.

So I've resorted to using a script mediator to modify the request. This is what I'd like to do:

```
//Get XML Request from message context    
var request= mc.getPayloadXML();

//Create a child node using standard E4X notation
var child = <id>1</id>;

//Append this XML to the request
request.appendChild(child);

//Replace the payload
mc.setPayloadXML(request);
```

Every time I try to submit this code, the WSO2 ESB API UI says that everything is cool. But when I check the underlying XML configuration, it is not cool. Where I defined "id" node is now just blank, as if it was filtered without my knowledge!

It would be great if I could add this element using a script mediator, but I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a pretty easy fix. Just use a CDATA section to have the XML parser ignore your code.

```
<![CDATA[ //YOUR CODE WITH XML INLINE// ]]>
```

Note that for some reason the WSO2 ESB XML Editor and UI will remove the CDATA section the next time you open your sequence for editing. I generally just copy out the XML configuration to a text file and paste it back into the configuration whenever it needs to be updated.

Not a perfect solution, but it'll get you over the line.